# Change save folder in burzum/cakephp-file-storage plugin

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm using a plugin to save files in CakePHP 3: **burzum/cakephp-file-storage**, 
everything works perfectly 
but now I need to change the directory where file is being saved dynamically (through the directory where 
the file is saved by parameter for example), how can I do this?

Path actual:

> [htdocs]\[AppName]\tmp[FileExtension.png]

It is possibly stay with the following structure for example:

> [htdocs]\[AppName-Images]\Products[FileExtension.png]

PHP Code:

```
public function saveFileLFS($stringSeparator, $storeName, $productName) 
{ 
  $key = $storeName . $stringSeparator . $productName . $stringSeparator . 
  $this->request->data['Media']['file']['name']; 
  if(StorageManager::adapter('Local')->write($key, 
     file_get_contents($this->request->data['Media']['file']['tmp_name']))){ 
  return true; 
}else 
{ 
  return false; 
} 
}
```

[Github Link](https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-file-storage)

Comment: I am having trouble installing this plugin can i message you some questions, it doesn't work for me

Comment: @artSir, I advise you to ask a question related to your problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32031237/getting-started-with-cakephp-file-storage-quickstart-guide 

I just need help getting started or if you could share your project so i can see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it ends up in `TMP` is that this is the *default* configuration that comes with the plugin. It goes to `TMP` because this is the only place besides logs that should be writeable in a proper application setup and the plugin should work out of the box. Maybe I'll change this in a future release (4.0) so that you have to configure it to use it, to make people aware of it.

For the local adapter change it like this:

```
StorageManager::config('Local', [
    'adapterOptions' => [ROOT . DS . 'file_storage' . DS], // Your base path here
    'adapterClass' => '\Gaufrette\Adapter\Local',
    'class' => '\Gaufrette\Filesystem'
]);
```

This will override the default. [Actually this is already documented and explained here.](https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-file-storage/tree/1.1.0/docs/Documentation/Specific-Adapter-Configurations.md#local-filesystem)

I recommend you to take a look at the [1.1.0 branch](https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-file-storage/tree/1.1.0) (currently release is 1.1.0-RC1). Some people already use it and I'm happy to get feedback about it. The whole way paths and file names are generated has been *completely* rewritten and abstracted into a set of classes called "[path builders](https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-file-storage/tree/1.1.0/src/Storage/PathBuilder)".

Comment: as you would to create directories dynamically when I'm storing a file? @burzum

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? Please read the documentation (there is plenty), it explains how it works internally, how to use, how it does things in a certain way. The path builders take care of directories and file names. Before the logic for that was part of the listeners, it has been abstracted in the overhaul branch to be a lot more clean and more easy to change.

Comment: I think the author meant is this: If it is possible to change the save directory (adapterOptions) on fly.

Comment: In theory yes but it *absolutly* doesnt make any sense. Thats what the listeners and now the path builders do. He didn't understood the whole concept then or didnt pay attention to the documentation if that's the real question. You set a base path for the local adaper (s3 knows a bucket, no local base for example) you then change the path that comes after your base or root path. This is done in the listeners and in the path builder branch (which is going to be merged soon) in the new path builder classes.