# Getting Started with cakephp-file-storage quickstart guide

Tags: php, cakephp

https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-file-storage/blob/3.0/docs/Tutorials/Quick-Start.md

Following the tutorial, it's all messed up or I am all messed up.

Three tables Products Images and ProductImages just trying to catch anything working.

Well first error in the upload.ctp productImage is not defined. Well duh, I see it in the controller its not set. I'm honestly don't know the purpose in passing that in the form create on an add. I know for an edit it will populate the data.

Next error When I submit i get an error ProductTable is not assosicated to ProductImages table well you see it right there in the tutorial, its listed as hasMany 'Images'.

So i change it to ProductImagesTable

And I get an error that upload is not defined, I'm assuming they are referencing from the controller and that its being inherited by the ImageStorageTable I changed it to uploadImage just trying not to get an error

I am just trying to get some kind of 'hello world' on how this works. If someone can just share me a project with this working. I can decipher what is wrong.

I would share my code but I just copied from the quickstart

Comment: Well, these are clearly mistakes in the docs, so I'd suggest that you create an issue ticket over at GitHub, so that it gets fixed. ps, StackOverflow is not the place where you ask for code, this is, or at least it should be, strictly programming related Q&A.

Comment: yea your right, sorry just so frustrating being trying all day. I will have to look at it again tomorrow and break it down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently started using CakePHP 3 too (I also had a bit of trouble), first of all I am using a **Local Storage** then this would be the appropriate setting

In file **bootstrap.php**

> C:\xampp\htdocs\[ProjectFolder]\config\bootstrap.php

```
StorageManager::config('Local', [
    'adapterOptions' => [TMP, true],
    'adapterClass' => '\Gaufrette\Adapter\Local',
    'class' => '\Gaufrette\Filesystem']
);
```

Put this block below use block (remember to use Burzum lib **use Burzum\FileStorage\Lib\StorageManager;**)

```
use Burzum\FileStorage\Lib\StorageManager;
use Cake\Cache\Cache;
use Cake\Console\ConsoleErrorHandler;
use Cake\Core\App;
use Cake\Core\Configure;
```

This line can be adjusted to your needs (had the Folder where file be storage).

```
'adapterOptions' => [TMP, true],
```

to (not necessary equals this)

```
'adapterOptions' => [ROOT . DS . 'PicturesResources' . DS],
```

This is my tables in MySql (Only two tables **products** and **medias** that store image paths (**media_types** is not important to this example))

```
CREATE TABLE products (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  product_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  quantity INT NOT NULL,
  sold INT NOT NULL,
  description VARCHAR(1000),
  price DECIMAL(7,2) NOT NULL,
  old_price DECIMAL(7,2) NOT NULL,
  visited INT NOT NULL,
  status INT NOT NULL,
  created DATETIME,
  modified DATETIME
);

CREATE TABLE media_types (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name_media_type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  created DATETIME,
  modified DATETIME
);

CREATE TABLE medias (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  media_type_id INT NOT NULL,
  product_id INT NOT NULL,
  path VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  created DATETIME,
  modified DATETIME,
  FOREIGN KEY media_type_key (media_type_id) REFERENCES media_types(id),
  FOREIGN KEY product_key (product_id) REFERENCES products(id)
);
```

I run **cake bake all products** and **cake bake all medias** and the result:

In **ProductsTable.php**

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('products');
    $this->displayField('id');
    $this->primaryKey('id');
    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
    $this->hasMany('Medias', [
        'className' => 'Medias',
        'foreignKey' => 'product_id'
    ]);
}
```

I add **'className' => 'Medias',** (I don't remember if its optional but I put it).

The **MediasTable.php** are the same generated by bake.

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('medias');
    $this->displayField('id');
    $this->primaryKey('id');
    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
    $this->belongsTo('MediaTypes', [
        'foreignKey' => 'media_type_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Products', [
        'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
}
```

My **upload method** in **ProductsController.php**

```
 public function upload() {

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $mediaTypeId = 1;
        $productId = 2;
        $path = $this->request->data['Media']['file']['tmp_name'];
        $inserted = $this->Insert->insertMedia($mediaTypeId, $productId, $path);

        //-------------------------------------------------------------------------

        $stringSeparator = '_';
        $storeName = 'StoreGYN';
        $productName = 'TestProduct';
        $saved = $this->UploadFile->saveFileLFS($stringSeparator, $storeName,
            $productName);

        if($inserted === true && $saved === true){
            $this->Flash->set(__('Upload successful!'));
        }
    }
}
```

I put the method responsible to **Store the file** in a **component** (it's optional):

```
public function saveFileLFS($stringSeparator, $storeName, $productName)
{
    $key = $storeName . $stringSeparator . $productName . $stringSeparator .
        $this->request->data['Media']['file']['name'];
    if(StorageManager::adapter('Local')->write($key,
        file_get_contents($this->request->data['Media']['file']['tmp_name']))){
        return true;
    }else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And put the method responsible to **Save the Path to Image** in a **component** too:

```
public function insertMedia($mediaTypeId, $productId, $path)
{
    $media = TableRegistry::get('Medias')->newEntity();
    $media->media_type_id = $mediaTypeId;
    $media->product_id = $productId;
    $media->path = $path;

    if(TableRegistry::get('Medias')->save($media)){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is the template, **pay atention in the input elements name** they should be the same as the keys `$this->request->data['Media']['file']['tmp_name'];` otherwise you will not be able to access the information sent in **form** (Including Image File).

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create(null, array(
    'type' => 'file'
));
echo $this->Form->file('Media.file');
echo $this->Form->error('file');
echo $this->Form->submit(__('Upload'));
echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

Notes: I'm using **XAMPP** and **CakePHP 3**

Comment: i will give you the credit for all the work. I finally got it working for me. You can't follow the quickstart guide, you have to follow the other instructions. And you have to run the migration in composer to get his tables. I originally thought that was only for cake2 users. And use cakePHP troubleshooting.

Comment: ricardo are you familar with delete? And did your media table extend the ImageStorageTable ?

Comment: In which file are you putting the methods (saveFileLFS and insertMedia) ?