# How to save images with Cakephp-File-Storage?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, file-storage

**UPDATE**

So I added some logs to the action upload in ProductsController and the method upload in MediasTable to find out what is happening. The entity from ProductsController `this->Products->Medias->newEntity()` was pass to MediasTable but it wasn't save.

[image]

It is necessary to upload the file to save the data in the db? Like if all the data is ok but the file is no present the event will be reject the data and do nothing in the db?

---

I'm using cakephp 3.1 with the file-storage plugin. I'm following the quickstart guide from the docs: [Quick-Start](https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-file-storage/blob/1.0/docs/Tutorials/Quick-Start.md) but I don't understand some parts and doesn't upload, insert in database neither make thumbnails.

This is my database:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
   id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   product_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   quantity INT NOT NULL,
   sold INT NOT NULL,
   description VARCHAR(1000),
   price DECIMAL(7,2) NOT NULL,
   old_price DECIMAL(7,2) NOT NULL,
   visited INT NOT NULL,
   status INT NOT NULL,
   created DATETIME,
   modified DATETIME
);

CREATE TABLE media_types (
   id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   name_media_type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   created DATETIME,
   modified DATETIME
);

 CREATE TABLE medias (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  media_type_id INT NOT NULL,
  product_id INT NOT NULL,
  path VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  created DATETIME,
  modified DATETIME,
  FOREIGN KEY media_type_key (media_type_id) REFERENCES media_types(id),
  FOREIGN KEY product_key (product_id) REFERENCES products(id)
);
```

MediasTable:

```
...
use Burzum\FileStorage\Model\Table\ImageStorageTable;

class MediasTable extends ImageStorageTable {
    public function initialize(array $config) {
        parent::initialize($config);
        $this->table('medias');
        $this->displayField('id');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->belongsTo('MediaTypes', [
            'foreignKey' => 'media_type_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('Products', [
            'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
    }
    ...
    public function upload($productId, $entity) {
        $media = $this->patchEntity($entity, [
            'adapter' => 'Local',
            'model' => 'Media',
            'foreign_key' => $productId
        ]);
        Log::write('debug', $media);
        return $this->save($media);
    }
}
```

ProductsTable:

```
class ProductsTable extends Table {
    public function initialize(array $config) {
        parent::initialize($config);
        $this->table('products');
        $this->displayField('id');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->hasMany('Medias', [
            'className' => 'Medias',
            'foreignKey' => 'foreign_key',
            'conditions' => [
                'Medias.model' => 'Media'
           ]
        ]);
    }
    ...
}
```

ProductsController:

```
class ProductsController extends AppController {
    public function upload($productId = null) {
        $productId = 2;
        $entity = $this->Products->Medias->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is(['post', 'put'])) {
            $entity = $this->Products->Medias->patchEntity(
                $entity,
                $this->request->data
            );
            if ($this->Products->Medias->upload($productId, $entity)) {
                $this->Flash->set(__('Upload successful!'));
            }
        }
        $this->set('productImage', $entity);
    }
    ...
}
```

In config/local_store.php is the same as the example (I include this file in boostrap.php)

```
...
$listener = new LocalFileStorageListener();
EventManager::instance()->on($listener);

$listener = new ImageProcessingListener();
EventManager::instance()->on($listener);

Configure::write('FileStorage', [
'imageSizes' => [
    'Medias' => [
        'large' => [
                ...
]);

FileStorageUtils::generateHashes();

StorageManager::config('Local', [
    'adapterClass' => '\Gaufrette\Adapter\Local',
    'adapterOptions' => [TMP, true],
    'class' => '\Gaufrette\Filesystem'
]);
```

upload.ctp

```
echo $this->Form->create($productImage, array('type' => 'file'));
echo $this->Form->file('file');
echo $this->Form->error('file');
echo $this->Form->submit(__('Upload'));
echo $this->Form->end();
```

In the quick start there is two upload methods: uploadImage and uploadDocument
but in the controller they use "upload".

There is another association in Products in the example, I need this?:

```
        $this->hasMany('Documents', [
        'className' => 'FileStorage.FileStorage',
        'foreignKey' => 'foreign_key',
        'conditions' => [
            'Documents.model' => 'ProductDocument'
        ]
    ]);
```

I found this question (from there is the db I'm using) [Getting Started with cakephp-file-storage quickstart guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32031237/getting-started-with-cakephp-file-storage-quickstart-guide) and upload and insert but doesn't make the thumbnails and if I change the table to ImageStoreTable shows an error "Class not found"

So if anybody can help me I will be very grateful!

Comment: By a quick look this seems right, but I don't understand your problem. The description you provide is basically "it's not working". Which doesn't help to debug it. Does it fire the event? Is something written to the table? Does the file appear on the server? Did you debug the post data...? I'll create a sample app with the tutorial code I'll publish on Github within the next few days.

Comment: Why do you need the medias und media_types tables? FileStorage is designed to avoid the need for such tables. The plugin **won't** work if you use your `medias` table. And I think this is what you're doing in your code.

Comment: Hi burzum, I'm just learning to use cakephp-file-storage and the other question in stackoverflow use that db. It works to upload files, so I keep using it. I tried to adapt the db, following the quick-start but it doesn't upload the file (does'nt apper in the server), don't show the flash message, don't write anything to db. I going to debug and later update the question. Thank you.